# How can I form a Google Map url which displays the map pointer without directions

Tags: google-maps

I need a url that shows the pointer **without** directions. At the moment I am using the scheme below. it asks for my current location. I want it to just display the map and the pointer.

> http://maps.google.com/maps?&daddr=51.55762,-0.282384(Hilton)

Comment: You need to grab the share link from google maps, like this: https://maps.google.com/maps?q=Hilton+London+Wembley,+Lakeside+Way,+Wembley,+United+Kingdom&hl=en&ll=51.55929,-0.282383&spn=0.007644,0.017037&sll=51.557671,-0.282713&sspn=0.000956,0.00213&oq=hil&hq=Hilton+London&hnear=Lakeside+Way,+Wembley+HA9+0WS,+United+Kingdom&t=m&z=16&iwloc=A

Answer (score 0):

You should be using places, like below:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/place/51.55762,-0.282384+(Hilton)
```